# Possibility of Email template validation using Karate API Framework

Tags: karate, email-validation

I am trying to validate the email template content like the Subject, Body, and Sender using Karate API Framework. To do this, I am using a Disposable email server (https://www.mail7.io/).

Finding it hard to get an approach. Is there any possibility using Karate we can achieve this?

I tried getting API Secret Keys and no credential is required to log in. I have no idea on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could tell, `mail7.io` provides a REST API. Then things should be very easy right, keep in mind that Karate is one of the most simple and expressive REST API clients around.  I suggest try this approach and ask a question with specifics if you get stuck.